# Ctrl-l, Ctrl-a, Ctrl-e do not work any more

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard

I accidentally deleted some files (do not remember what files), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> do not work anymore on my mac. I tried to reinstall bash using brew install bash. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Hi, this is an _ubuntu_ site, macs are off topic unless you're running Ubuntu on them. If you are, please [edit] your question and include the Ubuntu version. If you're running OSX, you could ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've probably ended up in 'vi' mode.

Type `set -o emacs` at your shell prompt and those <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys should work again. Put it in your `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: if you notice that adding `set -o emacs`  to `~/.bashrc` has no effect, check the `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` files and uncomment or remove the line `set editing-mode vi
`